# Html5 Video autoplay false not working in Mozilla

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mozilla, autostart

```
 <video  class="ahs-videoscntrl" src="videos/how-to-videos/Webinar Videos/Care Managment - Running Script.mp4" controls autostart="0" autoplay="false" > </video>

<script>    
$('.movie').click(function(){    
  $('.movie').get(0).play();    
});
</script> 

<video  class="movie ahs-videoscntrl" src="videos/how-to-videos/Webinar Videos/Appeals and Grievances.mp4" autostart="0"   autoplay="false" > </video>
```

Video playing on page load. Its working in Chrome not working in Mozilla. How to disable autoplay in Mozilla I tried with `autoplay="false" autostart="false" autostart="0"` need any new solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `preload="none"`

There's a known bug in Webkit that causes videos to buffer automatically, even if autobuffer is not set. It is currently fixed in the Safari nightlies (and may be fixed in Chrome, not really sure).

Comment: preload="none" same Out put in mozilla